rabbitmq-c CMake is failing with openssl option on windows
I am trying to build rabbitmq-c with openssl option on windows. I didn't find complete step-by-step process to build rabbitmq-c with openssl option.  CMake is failing with openssl option on Windows. I installed openssl win 32 version from https://slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL-3_3_0.exe and the given path as highlighted below but the build is failing with openssl not found. Can you please help in resolving this issue?



Adding an entry setting OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR to C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL-Win32/, then clicking 'configure'.

Thanks for the response, i tried with setting systemvariable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ,OPENSSL_LIBRARIES and OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR and adding entries to CMake in both cases it didn't work
